# Move text to other split

Tags: vim, split

I often work with files next to one another, in a `:vsplit`. Moving a line, or any obj from the file in one window to another is suboptimal. I was wondering if there is a movement I am missing.

What I do now: `3dd[ctrl]wwP[ctrl]ww`. Roughly:

- Remove a bunch of lines (could be anything from a line to any text-obj to a visual selection)
- Move custor to other window.
- Paste
- Move cursor back to other window.

Vim in *vimdiff* mode allows `:diffput` and `:diffpull` to move lines in a diff between the two splits. Is there something similar for any two files in any two splits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such generic command.

`:diffput` and `:diffget` are possible because the origin and target are known: the location of your cursor corresponds to a specific range in both buffers so it's "easy" for Vim to know what to do with what and where.

A generic "take this, put it over there and come back" command is harder to design because not much is known about the target and a lot of things must be infered from the context of the command, your window layout or even the kind (linewise, characterwise, blockwise) of the text you are moving around. An important thing to decide, for example is "how to paste": `p`, `P`, `:put` or even if we need to re-indent. A very simplistic implementation would look like this:

```
:command! To :wincmd w|put|wincmd w
```

but it's obviously not smart enough to be really generic. I'm afraid what you want requires quite a bit of thinking and vimscript.